# Retrieving identifiers of paper that cite another paper

Tags: python, citations, scopus, pybliometrics

I try to retrieve the identifiers of papers that cite other papers using Scopus API (pybliometrics).

Example:

- The paper Franke et al. 2020 has in total 3 citations (I get this number using `pybliometrics.scopus.CitationOverview`)
- Is there any way to get the identifiers (dois, titles,...) of these 3 papers? If the Scopus API does not support this feature, does the Google Scholar API?

Comment: A general response (without necessarily using `pybliometrics`): https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/137281/is-it-possible-to-automatically-obtain-cited-by-lists/150487#150487

Answer (score 3):

In Scopus this is possible via `REF(<EID>)` (alternatively, use the DOI). You use this in the ScopusSearch API:

```
from pybliometrics.scopus import ScopusSearch

cited = "2-s2.0-85068268027"
q = f"REF({cited})"
s = ScopusSearch(q)
citing = s.results
```

Object `citing` is a list of nameduples, as explained in https://pybliometrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classes/ScopusSearch.html.

Whether Goole Scholar is able to do that I don't know.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I only get the number of citations for the paper "2-s2.0-85068268027" using `citing[0].citedby_count` (the result is 5) but not the DOIs of these 5 papers.

Comment: You mustn't use the `citedby_count`. Obviously, that's just a number. You must search for a documents that the cite the document you want. Then extract the information 1-by-1 from the results set.